# Delegating A Form Object's Attributes To The Model It Wraps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model

I have broken out some complex nested-object-creation into a form object that I am using for both `new`/`create` and `edit`/`update`.

For the `edit` form I need to expose values already present on the model. It's a chunky model with a large number of attributes and associations, and I need to expose most of these via the edit form. Obviously I could write getters for each one which pull the value from the model:

```
def example
   @model.example
end
```

Or use delegate:

```
delegate :example, to: @model
```

But both these solutions involve a lot of repetition.

This is the first time I've used a form object for an `edit`/`update` scenario, and I've been unable to find a single example to crib from (every example seems to shy away from this aspect and stick with a `new`/`create` form object where an empty form is expected).

**So in a form object used for an edit form, how should I expose the model's attributes and associations to the form?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could implement a `method_missing` on your form object, but i think that this is against the idea of exposing a clear API to the form via a form object.

i think it's fine to have some repetition going on, it's a mapping layer. they are repetitions in 99% of the cases.

Comment: Thanks. My spidey sense starts tingling any time I'm repeating something. I guess if I automate the mapping , then that in itself is a straightjacket, and I suppose if everything is a direct mapping all the form object is just mediating the same coupling between model and form.

Comment: yes, exactly. there would no reason to create a from-object if it's bound so closely to the model.